# Spark SQL vs Impala For ETL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, etl, impala, hue

Currently, we are using traditional data warehouse ETL tool IBM DataStage. We are looking to migrate these jobs. These jobs mostly include join and transformation to derive fact tables. Which would be the better technology to migrates such jobs? We are using hue oozie with Impala queries for ETL, should we looking to use spark sql for ETL rather than Impala queries?

Answer (score 0):

how r u implementing type 2 etc. In Hive ,Impala etc. As for me the whole Big data stack is useless for Prod env

U not only append data but update in Bulk to load data like Type 2  . 
  for data correction u need lots of adhoc queries,update ,delete insert .
  Run lots of adhoc queries from support /dev team for finding result
    discrepancy etc.
All the above 3 points make this stack useless .

Use case is 
Lots of Lots of data where output is some estimation not correctness  , one big fat table , with delete and drop or unstructured data